# Manhwa/novel where a sick girl runs away from home and cross dresses to become the butler/closest aide of the boy whose presence heals her

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's about a girl who transmigrates into the body of a white haired noble girl who has a sickness that can only be cured be being around a specific person or she dies in some years.

From what I remember, she runs away from home and cross dresses to become the butler/closest aide of the boy whose presence heals her. And from what I remember, he's also sick but because plot he survives longer than her, since he's a character in the story the FL transmigrated into. She pretends to be obsessed with him to drink medicine in some scenes I remember.

What's the name of this manwha/lightnovel?

Comment: Is it a manhwa or a light novel or both?

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Surviving As An Obsessive Servant](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/surviving-as-an-obsessive-servant)***...?

> **I’ve died of the same rare disease 3 times in the world of a BL novel. I can’t die like this anymore. So I took special measures.** ‘Let’s just put a spoon on the well-prepared medicine table!’ Young master, I won’t miss a single drop of medicine or even a breath! **I disguised myself as a servant to serve the sick young master. Even the spirit power from his breath would heal me,** so what could be better than this! But serving the said individual was not easy… I’m a do-if-you-must kind of girl. While I was at it, I took good care of my master, who was my lifesaver. As well as serving him, I hugged him, carried him, and became his legs. I wonder if he recognized my true value as the heir of a prestigious dukedom. The young master would occasionally glare at me, but he didn’t kick me out. Now, I have recovered and repaid my gratitude. It was time to figure out my escape plan… But something was off about the young master. “You said you liked me so much, so where are you trying to run off to?” “...” “You said you’d die without me.” Gradually, he began to have the look of a hungry predator.

A woman is hit by a truck and reincarnated as a white-haired woman in the world of a Boy's Love novel. The character she's been reincarnated as suffers from the same disease as the male protagonist of the novel and only his breath can cure her, so she cuts her hair short, disguises herself as a man, and applies to becomes his attendant so she can be near him.

[image: Surviving As An Obsessive Servant, chapter 1, page 2.] [image: Surviving As An Obsessive Servant, chapter 1, page 3.]